# ffmpeg ecplise debugging

Tags: c++, gdb, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg with my application ( Ubuntu ), to be able to better understand the way things work I want to be able to debug through it, for that, while compiling I am using the following './configure' options:

- --disable-stripping
- --enable-debug=3
- --extra-cflags="-gstabs+"

Having that set, I am able to step through 'ffmpeg' with the debugger ( gdb ), however, I am not able to evaluate any of the variables, only the code position is resolvable...

What am I doing wrong? why can't I evaluate the variables?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only thing missing was the **--disable-optimizations** configure switch